# How would different verbal emphasis in spoken English change the meaning of these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, writing, listening, prosody

What is the meaning of verbal emphasis in Spoken English?  For example, the difference between the following three sentences and how emphasis changes the semantics?

- ***I*** love you.
- I ***love*** you.
- I love ***you***.
- I love you ***very*** much.

Are there other ways of verbally emphasizing "I love you" to express different meanings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *I* love you.

"It's *me* who loves you." This would be said in the context where you're contrasting with someone else:

> "He likes you, but *I* love you!"

## I *love* you.

You're emphasizing the fact that it's love, rather than anything else. This is also the emphasis you would use if you want to emphasize the whole sentence.

For example:

> "I'm moving to South Africa!"
> "What?! You can't! I *love* you!"

## I love *you*.

It's *you* that I love. Again, contrasting with another person, but it's the loved person who's being contrasted now, not the one who is doing the loving.

> "Of course there's no-one else. I love *you*, silly."

## I love you *very* much.

Here you're just emphasizing the degree of the love.

## Other ways of verbally emphasizing "I love you" to express different meanings

I can think of a couple:

**I *do* love you.**

This "do" is a common way of expressing emphasis. [Read more in this answer.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13486/3976)

***I* love *you*.**

This can be a way of saying "I love you too" if it comes after "I love you".

> "I love you."
> "And *I* love *you*."

This emphasis could come after "Bob loves Tom" or something, it doesn't have to come after "I love you".

Answer (score 3):

To put it simply, *verbal emphasis* is the way of stretching a particular word or changing a pitch or volume in the sentence to emphasize it. Emphasizing a proper word may change the meaning of the sentence (download from the link).

> *I* love you - It's *me* who loves you; nobody else does that 
>   I *love* you - it's not just friendship or simply caring. 
>   I love *you* - and nobody else 
>   I love you *very* much - my love is more intense, high degree.

[Good read here](http://www.bcpss.org/bbcswebdav/xid-54381_4) (it'll download an MS Word file and is not corrupt).

*Are there other ways of verbally emphasizing "I love you" to express different meanings?* - I think you covered every word in it, that's all! Bringing in other words would change the meaning then.

Comment: It's not always accomplished by stretching the word. Sometimes pitch or volume can indicate emphasis.

Comment: @starsplusplus by *stretching* I meant all of them. When you stretch something, you change pitch/volume/intensity of that word. I used that as an umbrella term. Thanks anyway. Edited.

Comment: @MaulikV I believe that "stretching a particular word" doesn't mean raising pitch or volume to many people. I might be wrong on that, but obviously I'm not alone. I think we can emphasis without having to stretch the emphasized word or syllable out.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, I agree. I assumed "stretching a particular word" meant elongating it. I wouldn't have considered it an umbrella term to also include pitch or volume at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here, emphasis is being used to put things straight, to banish confusion. The thing emphasized is more important than the thing not emphasized, in a relationship of duality, or perhaps polarity. To illustrate:

- **I** love you, not her, she just wants your money. *Emphasis on the person who loves.*
- I **love** you, I don't just like you, darling I love you. *Emphasis on the sentiment.*
- I love **you**, not him, you fool! *Emphasis on the person loved.*
- I love you **very** much, even if I don't say it very often. *Possibly tinged with guilt; compensating for not having said 'I love you' often enough.*

Are there other ways of saying *I love you*...?

Yes. "Love you" can be heard between intimates as a way of saying goodbye.

"**Honestly**, I love you" means I don't love you but I want you to think I do. Etc.