# When can we omit "does" in the question sentence

Tags: grammar, verb-forms, question-marks

I am learning Duolingo English course, I saw a sentence like this:

> Who uses the wheels?

But should we use something below?

> Who does use the wheels?

What's difference between two? When can I omit the word **does** in a question sentence?

Thanks

Jake

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/auxilliary-do-with-the-subject-in-questions

Comment: @DamkerngT. Your link is very helpful. Can I mark it as a duplicated question?

Comment: I just want to know the burning question that nobody here has addressed.  ***Who does, in fact, use the wheels?***

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37909/94993

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without negation, *does* is used to question the truth of a statement, or to add emphasis. For example:

> Does she use the wheels? *Yes/No/I don't know*

In your example, you're not asking about whether someone uses the wheels or not, but who uses the wheels, *if* anyone does at all. For instance:

> Who uses the wheels? *I do/she does/Alice does/Bob does*

Does can also be used for emphasis in certain variants of English (US, UK, Aus, Canadian). For example:

> Alice: "She doesn't use the wheels."
>
> Bob: "Who does use the wheels?"

In this case, the use of does would be accompanied by a pitch movement, to show emphasis, usually with it being pronounced with a higher pitch than the rest of the sentence.