# Do I have to use “do” in any “wh-” question?

Tags: questions, inversion, do-support

1. - What did you say?
   - What you said?
2. - What did you wear?
   - What you wore?
3. - Where did you go?
   - Where you go?

I know that sometimes in English, people do not use **“do”** in “wh-” questions. I have heard somewhere that people do not use **“do”** when the answer is a proper noun or a unique thing. Am I right?

Comment: What you said./Where you go/etc.. are Wh-clauses. Not Wh- questions

Comment: What about in other wh questions? You know I thought my question might become misleading. Yes they are like clauses. But I mean sonething else. There are sometimes I cannot remember that depending on answer, they do not use "do" or "does" in some wh questins.

Comment: Note that questions that use verbs of being do not require *do*: "*Where **are** my shoes?*", versus "*Where **did** I put my shoes?*" I cannot think of any rule about not using *do* with proper nouns.

Comment: @apsillers - Which bus goes to the down town ? VS Which bus does go to the diwn town? How should I quickly figure out that I should make the first one?

Comment: @user5036 Aha, now I understand the kind of question you mean! I'll post a new answer.

Comment: In early modern English, there were other proper forms: *What said you*, *What wore you*?, *Where go you?* Shakespeare wrote: *Where goes Cesario?* (The forms we use today, like *Where does Cesario go?* would also have been grammatical then, but a brief search of Shakespeare suggests that with *where*, they were somewhat less common.)

Comment: @PeterShor and the key pattern to notice there is that the first verb still must come before the subject.

Answer (score 21):

The rule is that Do support is called into play after a *Wh-*interrogative when subject/auxiliary inversion is called for and the verb is not headed by BE or an auxiliary. Consequently:

> You do not use *do* after a *Wh-*
>
> - **a)** when the *Wh-* word is the **Subject** of the verb, or is a 'determiner' on the subject—subject/auxiliary inversion does not occur when this is the case.
>
>   > Who **told** you that?
>   >     Which bus **goes** downtown?
> - **b)** when the tensed verb is a form of *BE*—subject/auxiliary inversion is required, but *BE* is always treated as an auxiliary, even when the copular or behavioral sense is intended, so *do* support is not needed.
>
>   > Who **are** you?
>   >     How old **are** you?
>   >     Where **were** you yesterday?
> - **c)** when the tensed verb is an auxiliary: *BE*, *HAVE*, or a modal—this auxiliary inverts with the subject and *do* support is not needed:
>
>   > Why **have** you come here?
>   >     What **is** being done to you?
>   >     What **can** you do?

In the following questions the tensed verb is not *BE* or an auxiliary, and the *Wh-* word is not the subject of the verb, so subject/auxiliary inversion is required and *do* support **is** needed to supply the auxiliary:

> **Q:** What did you say? → **A:** I said *X*.
>   **Q:** Which shirt did you wear? → **A:** I wore *X*.
>    *What* you are asking about is the Direct Object of the verbs, so the questions need *do* support.
>
> **Q:** Who did you give it to? → **A:** I gave it *to X*.
>    *Who* you are asking about is the Indirect Object of *give*, so the question needs *do* support.
>
> **Q:** Where did you go? → **A:** I went *to X*.
>    *Where* represents your destination, a complement to the verb *go*.
>
> **Q:** Why did you go? → **A:** I went *because X*.
>    *Why* represents your reason, a modifier to the clause headed by *go*.

Comment: I think "Who did you give it to" should be "_Whom_ did you give it to", since, as you point out, it is the object.

Comment: If you wanted to be really fussy, @GentlePurpleRain, it would be *To whom did you give it?*, but not many people actually talk like that.

Comment: @TRiG Agreed: that's the kind of nonsense up with which most people will not put.

Comment: @TRiG I was always taught that the rule against ending a sentence with a preposition is really just a completely made up myth, and that such a rule has never actually been followed.

Comment: @Daniel It has never been followed much in speech, except by the very highly educated. It was first advanced by Dryden in the late 17th century, but in a context where it is clear that what he had in mind was ending a line of verse on an infelicitously *stressed* preposition. In the 18th century several grammarians *recommended* avoiding the stranded preposition in certain registers, especially oratory, on prosodic grounds. It only hardened into a rule in the early 19th century; but it was pretty strictly observed in formal and academic prose for more than 150 years. ...

Comment: ... Stranded prepositions only started to reappear in these very strict dialects in my lifetime, along with other colloquial forms which had been excluded for several generations. So it is incorrect to say that the 'rule' has "never been followed". Indeed, it is still followed in the most conservative formal dialects, such as law and the sciences, and many people (including many teachers of high school English and ESL) still hold to it as an article of faith.

Comment: Why cannot we 'star' the answers? Favorite Answers? Brilliant!

Comment: Note that in case of emphasis you may actually have auxiliary "do" even if Wh- word is the Subject (case a)) - see [Auxilliary “do” with the subject in questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13469/auxilliary-do-with-the-subject-in-questions)

Answer (score 6):

Your questions without an auxiliary ***do*** are not correct:

> What did you say? (correct)
>
> What you said? (**not** correct)

The second form is never correct. Note that it is correct as a relative clause:

> I heard **what you said.**

As a stand-alone sentence, however, "*What you said?*" is never grammatical.

---

Note that questions with verbs of being do *not* need an auxiliary like ***do***:

> Where **are** my shoes? (correct)
>
> What **is** your name? (correct)
>
> When **was** my brother here? (correct)

---

In all my examples above, the "wh-" question words act as **nouns** or **adverbs**:

> **What** did you wear? I wore **my red dress**.
>
> **When** was my brother here? He was here **during the last thunderstorm.**

*However*, some question words act as **adjectives** to modify nouns. In that case, you do not need a form of ***do***:

> **Which** bus goes to New York? (correct)
>
> **This** bus goes to New York.
>
> **Whose** dog wants to play?
>
> **My** dog wants to play.

Comment: It's grammatical as an echo question.  "I'm asking what I said." "**What you said?**  Why are you asking that?" "I told you, I have amnesia!"

Answer (score -1):

Partially yes, it is optional to use the ***do*** auxiliary in any specific cases.

**These are grammar rules:**
When **what**, **who**, **which** or **whose** is the subject or part of the subject, we do not use the auxiliary. You do no need to use ***do*** auxiliary. Take in account that the sentence word pattern order must be *subject + verb?* instead of *Wh + do auxiliary + subject + verb?*.

Examples:

- What fell off the wall?
- Which horse won?
- Who bought this?
- Whose phone rang?

Take in account that it is **optional** to use the ***do*** auxiliary. Usually is used to give more emphasis or an idea about the desire to know the answer.
Thus:

- What does the wall fell off?
- Which did horse win?
- Who did this buy?
- Whose did phone ring?

Are also valid. Both convey a desire to know the answer, but this convey an extra level of desire.

Extra example:

- A: Ronald Price lives in that house, doesn’t he?
- B: No. He moved out.
- A: ***So who does live there?*** (non-emphatic question: ***So who lives there?***)
- B: Actually, his son is living there now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Updated

Answer (score -3):

These are all idiomatic:

```
What kind of clothes does she like to wear?
What kind of clothes did she wear when she was in college?
What kind of clothes was she wearing when she went to the dance?
What is she wearing to the dance?
What have I got in my pocket?
What do I have in my pocket?
What is in my pocket?
What was in my pocket?
Now, what was I going to say?
What do you have to say about that?!

Where do you put the coin in this vending machine?

Who do you have for calculus next semester?

When is the train coming?
When does this train arrive in Berlin?

Why do you ask?
Why even ask her?  She won't give you a definite answer.

What to wear?

When to go?

Hmmm, who to be for Hallowe'en?

Why take risks when you could play it safe?
```

Comment: this isn't an answer in any way