# When to use did in a question?

Tags: past-tense, questions, interrogatives

I have a dilemma. I know how to use this, but I'm trying to explain it to someone and I can't find a logical explanation.

So here it is:

> 1. Who called last night?
> 2. Who did you call last night?

Why does the second sentence contain "did" when the first one doesn’t?

Comment: The second sentence is technically incorrect: it should be "Whom did you call last night?" However, many native English speakers confuse _who_ and _whom_, and the intended meaning will be deduced from the word order rather than the case of the pronoun.

Comment: Closely related: [Do I have to use “do” in any “wh-” question?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37902/1654)

Comment: @200_ Well, and the form of the verb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Michael Swan explains this clearly in his Practical English Usage (2005.481).

> When  *who, which, what* or *whose* is the subject (or part of the
>   subject), *do* is not normally used: Compare:
>
> - *Who **phoned**?* (*Who* is the subject.)
> - *Who **did** you **phone**?* (**Who** is the object.)
>
> [...] But *do* can be used after a subject question word for emphasis,
>   to insist on an answer:
>
> - *Well, tell us - what **did happen** when your father found you?*

Comment: This makes it pretty clear, but I have one more curiosity. What is the subject in your second example? Is it "you"?

Comment: @ Alex. Yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

If the Wh- word represents the subject then we don't need to use *do*,  and we don't need to change the subject and auxiliary verb.

However, It can be a bit difficult to understand if *who/which* is the subject. One way to find this information is to give a full answer to the question:

- **X** called.
- I called **X**.

If X is the subject of the answer, then it's usually the subject of the question, and we don't need *do* here. If it isn't the subject we need *do*:

- Who called
- Who did I call?

Hope this is helpful!