# "Why all the..." or "what did all the..."?

Tags: grammar

> The forest was spooky. I suddenly wished we’d come during the
>   day. Why (did) all the trips had to be at night?

Do I need to add *did* in the example above? When do I have to add did and when not?

Comment: Yes, you need it here.  I'm having trouble coming up with a clear rule for when you do and do not use it.

Comment: The sentence should read, "Why **did** all the trips **have** to be **at** night?"

Comment: Closely related: [Do I have to use “do” in any “wh-” question?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/37902/1654)

Comment: @apsillers' link should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern English, the creation of an interrogative sentence by reversing the subject and the verb is archaic except with certain verbs.  Normally now, the verb "do" is used as an auxiliary.  So yes, you have to use did here.  Also, the main verb is an infinitive, so it doesn't inflect.  Correct is

> Why did all the trips have to be in the night?

And in present tense:

> Why do all the trips have to be in the night?

Now, look at these:

> How do you make biscuits?
>   How does he make biscuits?
>   Can he make biscuits?
>   Must he make biscuits?
>   Should he make biscuits?
>   Does he have to make biscuits?
>   How dare he make biscuits?
>   How does he dare to make biscuits?
>   Does he have any biscuits?
>   Has he any biscuits?  (This is generally BrE)
>   Is he a biscuit maker?

So, you don't use *do* when using any form of *be*.  *Have* can go either way.  Auxiliary verbs that can replace *do* are *can*, *must*, *should*, and *dare*.  (There are probably others I haven't thought of.)  Also, *have* and *will* replace *do* in past perfect and future tense, respectively.