# Use "does" in front of another verb in a question?

Tags: questions, do-support, subject-auxiliary-inversion

1. > What time does sound good to you?
2. > What time sounds good to you?

Is there a difference?

Comment: Related: [Do I have to use “do” in any “wh-” question?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37909/3281).

Answer (score 8):

With ordinary sentences we distinguish questions from statements by flipping the subject and the auxiliary verb (*Subj/Aux inversion*), and if there is no auxiliary in the statement form, we bring in *do* to serve the auxiliary function (*Do support*):

> **This time has been** very pleasant →Q: **Has this time been** pleasant?
>   **This time seems** good to me →Q: **Does this time seem** good to you?

But when you ask a question using a *wh-* word as the subject, or as a determiner on the subject, the *wh-* word is what tells your hearer that this is a question; there is no need for Subj/Aux inversion, and therefore no need for *Do support* either:

> **This time sounds** good to me →Q: **What time sounds** good to you?

ADDED:
As snailboat points out, *does* can be used to emphasize contrast with a prior negative:

> **A:** Shall I put us down for the seven o'clock show?
>   **B:** No, I don't much care for seven.
>   **A:** Well, what about two o'clock? Does that sound good to you?
>   **B:** No, two's no good for me.
>   **A:** (*exasperated*)Then what time ***does*** sound good to you?

Answer (score 1):

If "who/what" or "what/which+noun" is the subject you don't use the question form with to do. So sentence 1 is wrong and sentence 2 is correct. http://www.englishgrammar.org/subject-object-question/

Examples:

- Who goes there? Who has done it? Who said this?
- What is it? What's the matter? What makes the Earth turn round its axis?

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence sounds wrong. The second sentence is fine.

But the following sentences that use "does" are correct:

> What time does the train arrive?
>
> What time do we eat?