# "Who pays" vs "who does pay"

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

- > Who **pays** for that?
- > Who **does pay** for that?

What is the difference between these two sentences? Are both grammatically correct?

Comment: Related: **[Using do-support in wh-questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37902/do-i-have-to-use-do-in-any-wh-question)**. In short, **does** is not necessary, because **who** assumes the Subject position.

Comment: The first sentence would be the normal, most common way.  The second sentence is not the normal way of phrasing the question, but it is possible as an example of the [emphatic do](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/ask_about_english/071112/), in which we use "*do* (verb)" to emphasize something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is correct and the best way to say it.

A simple rule when using the interrogative pronouns with a verb in a question. If the question is about the subject of the verb, you don't include do, does or did:

> Who **pays** for that?
>
> Who **let** the dogs out?

In case the question is about the object, you do include them:

> Who **does** Santos love?
>
> Who **did** the teacher punish?

Note that those examples are in simple present and simple past only. Things might change in other tenses.

**Update:**

Also note that You might use the second sentence if you want to use the **emphatic do**. The **emphatic do** is simple used when you want to emphasize a verb. For instance:

> - I don't think you like this song.
>
> - Come on! I really **do** like it a lot.

There is also the example *stangdon* mention below in the comments.

Comment: The second is not necessarily wrong; it could be an example of the **emphatic do**.  "The city council doesn't pay for that?  The regional government doesn't pay for that?  Well, who *does* pay for that?"

Comment: @stangdon I believe you're right. I was looking for a way to include the **emphatic do** in the answer.

Comment: In your questions we have no relative pronouns  but interrogative pronouns or simply question words. There are no relative clauses.