# When does the museum open vs. When is the museum open

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I'm reading a book which represents sentences of two languages in parallel. I've noticed that one of the sentences is:

> When **does** the museum open?

My question is: Is it not supposed to be with a different type of auxiliary verb (be) rather than the auxiliary verb **do** - as in the following?

> When **is** the museum open?

...since **open** is an adjective in this context.

The word **open** is used to be used in this context as an adverb. Always when I listen to people who talk about the work times of places they say: it IS open between such hour to such hour. I've never heard that someone said "it opens between..." and used it as a verb. Maybe I'm mistaken and it is in use as verb in such context in native English spoken countries.

[image: does]

Comment: Ah! I understand. No, _open_ is a verb, not an adjective. The declarative form of the wh-question is: _**The museum does open when.**_

Comment: Have you used a dictionary to learn about the verb _to open?_ _"When do you **open** the store?_ _"It **opens** sometime between 8:00 and 9:00."_

Comment: Yes, I have. Before I asked my question I knew that it can be a verb or an adjective, but this is not the point. The point is that which one of them is used to be in the context that I represented. I edited my question and maybe it will make my question clearer.

Comment: The two sentences are different. We say _"The museum opens at 9 o'clock"_ (verb _to open_) and _"The museum is open at 9 o'clock."_ (_open_ is an adjective and complement of the copula.) Either one is fine, although the former is more idiomatic in the declarative. In the interrogative, we would usually use the _does_ form.

Comment: Then actually are both of them in use equally. I'm asking it because this is the first time that I see such use. Normally when we talk about verbs it's about human or other form of life that can act, but museum is inanimate.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about "form of life" here. There is no preference for a living actor in the choice of usage. A store _does open at 6,_ a hammer _does strike a nail._ You might find @StoneyB's answer [**here**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37909/37009) enlightening.

Comment: Yes, that's a normal sentence,  just like the one in Russian at the bottom of your image.

Comment: He is confused because the inanimate thing produces an action, right?But that exists in any language, clocks strike, buses go and doors open.

Comment: V.V. you're right as well as the other comments here. but as you know, even we can see sometimes humanization, it doesn't say that it an be applied by us in any case. Therefore in such cases the question is what is the acceptable or known uses. As I understood from the comments above both are correct and useful. But see here: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=is+open&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjht_Px9IHQAhUHkCwKHYixAuMQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=613

Comment: The verb _to do_ does not require a living subject. If someone taught you that, they didn't know what they were talking about. Forget all about it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for all your comments and answers to me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

In the sentence, "When is the museum open," the word "open" acts as an adjective.

Whereas in the sentence, "When does the museum open," the word "open" acts as a verb.

The first sentence would be used when you want to know the time frame of when the store is available for business (The store is open 6am to 7pm).

The second sentence is used to ask what time the store opens its doors; this would be answered with a specific point in time, not a range of times (The store opens at 9).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the first form if waiting to get in

> Me: When does the museum open?
>    Them: In 25 minutes.

I would use the second form when planning future travel.

> Me: When is the museum open?
>   Them: 9 a.m. to 5 p.m. Mondays through Fridays except bank holidays.

To me the first form is suggestive of an event (opening) and the second is suggestive of a state (being open), hence the subtle connotation.

But really there isn't a lot of difference and the other party will work out what you mean by context.